# QGIS Desktop 2.12.3 WebApp Builder

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, openlayers-2, boundless-suite

I want to use the WebApp Builder in QGIS 2.12.3
But I can not find the QGIS Web App Builder in my QGIS version 2.12.3

Like this one: 
http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/06/building-openlayers-3-web-app-without-writing-code/

When I go to plugins it just shows the three options: Phyton console, manage / install plugins and InaSAFE.

I also tried to install all useful plugins like qgis2web GeoSuite and OpenLayers plugin.

Do I need to install the 2.8 version?

Answer (score 6):

To install the **Web App Builder**, you will need to download this directly from the [Boundless GitHub](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/), or more specifically from the [Web App Builder GitHub page](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-webappbuilder-plugin/releases).

(*Note that it is not available in the QGIS Official Plugin Repository as according to this [post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Web-App-Builder-plugin-td5230559.html), it may still be in the bug-fixing phase.*)

Download and extract the .zip file into `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/python/plugins`. The plugin needs to be enabled from the *Manage and Install Plugins...* menu. Once done, it should be available in the **Web menu** as mentioned by @TomChadwin:

[image: Web App Builder]

Comment: How to enable from that menu? it's not showing up for me after extracting the files like you've said

Comment: @Luffydude - Did you extract the files when QGIS was already running? If so, restart QGIS.

Comment: Oh it worked. it appears under installed and I just have to check the box. Thanks!

Comment: @Luffydude - Awesome, glad you found it =)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Web menu. That's certainly where qgis2web installs.